# Python confusion matrix for classification

Tags: python, classification, confusion-matrix

```
import numpy as np

A = ([100, 900, 0, 0])

def err_metric(CM): 
  
TP = CM.iloc[A[0]]
FP = CM.iloc[A[1]]
FN = CM.iloc[A[2]]
TN = CM.iloc[A[3]]

precision =(TP)/(TP+FP)
recall  =(TP)/(TP+FN)
specificity =(TN)/(TN + FP)
False_negative_rate =(FN)/(FN+TP)
False_positive_rate =(FP)/(FP+TN)
accuracy  =(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN)
spatial_accuracy = (TP) / (TP + FN + FP)
f_measure =2*(( precision * recall)/( precision + recall))
print("Precision : ",precision)
print("Recall: ",recall)
print("Specificity : ",specificity)
print("False negative rate: ",False_negative_rate)
print("False positive rate: ",False_positive_rate)
print("Accuracy: ",accuracy)
print("Spatial accuracy: ",spatial_accuracy)
print("F-measure: ",f_measure)
```

I want to print out the above specified Confusion_matrix values, and nothing is shown, when I run the program in google collab. (TP = 100, FP = 900, FN,TN = 0).
At what part did I made an error?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that you opened a function but you didn't call that function.
the thing is you can call it like this err_metric.precision